# Intuition behind the substitution method of integration

Tags: calculus

I want to know what is the rationale behind substitution method of integration.I'm very familiar with the following sort of integration but I don't understand why we substitute 
i.e use one variable in terms of another variable.
For the integral, $\int 2x\sqrt{x^2+3}\,dx$ we can use the substitution method in the following manner.
If $z=x^2+3,$ then $dz=2xdx$. We have $\int\sqrt{z}dz$.

My question is that why $\int\sqrt{z}dz$=$\int 2x\sqrt{x^2+3}\,dx$? Is there rationale behind it?

Comment: The rationale is it reduces the problem to an easier problem that we know how to solve. We then solve the easier problem and unravel the solution $z$ in terms $x$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: @Mattos I think the question is now why we would _want_ to do this, but why we think this method will give a correct answer.

Comment: @DavidK I tried to answer both of those questions, the first with my comment and the second with the link embedded in my comment, as I didn't think the question was very clear.

Comment: @Mattos I didn't follow the link; that's why I missed that half of the explanation.

Comment: It's depressing to see this question closed. I'd like to see some interesting thoughts on it by the people who voted to close. When the question was here over three years ago the answers just regurgitated the proof of the substitution rule, but didn't address the real issue of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Substitution can seem intuitive when approached from the perspective of the *differential*. Rather than the formal definition of the differential, here are a couple of examples that make the meaning pretty clear:

$ d \ (x^3 + a) = 3x^2dx $, and similarly $ d \ (\sin x) = \cos x \ dx $, and so on.

In other words:
\begin{equation*}
d \ [f(x)] = \frac{df}{dx} \cdot dx
\end{equation*}

Now if you think of the $dx$ or $dz$ term that appears in an integral in the same way, you will notice that this term defines the so called "variable of integration".

In particular, considering the example of the integral given in the question, notice first that:

$ d\, (x^2 + 3) = 2x\, dx $

And therefore, the suggested integral can be rewritten as:

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int 2x \ \sqrt{x^2 + 3} \ \ dx &=&  \int \sqrt{x^2 + 3} \ \ (2x\, dx) \\
 &=& \int \sqrt{x^2 + 3} \ \ d\, (x^2 + 3) \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{[using the differential noted above]}
\end{eqnarray*}

The integral now looks like it is of the form:

\begin{equation*}
\int \sqrt{z} \ dz
\end{equation*}

The process of substitution is effectively equivalent to the above process.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continous, let $F$ be its antiderivative and let $g : [\alpha,\beta] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be differentiable, strictly nondecreasing andso that we have $g(\alpha) = a, g(\beta) = b$. Under these assumptions, due to the fundamental theorem of calculus we have

$$F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

but also

$$F(g(\beta)) - F(g(\alpha)) = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (F \circ g)' dx = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} F'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) dx = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) $$

As $g(\alpha) = a, g(\beta) = b$, we conclude

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) $$